# Automatically convert pixel to rem values in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

The idea is to write `16prem` (think: pixel-to-rem) and have Visual Studio Code automatically substitute with `1rem`. The IDE would therefore need to recognize that there is a number immediately followed be the keyword `prem`, divide the number by 16 and give back the result, followed by `rem`.

Input: `16prem` → Output: `1rem`
Input: `40prem` → Output: `2.5rem`

I tried achieving this via Visual Studio Code snippet transformations but am both new to the VS Code snippet syntax and RegEx. Does anyone know if this can be done?

Comment: and what if I put a 25px font on the `html` tag

Answer (score 0):

There are free extensions to do this
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LAGS.pixel-to-rem-converter

Answer (score 0):

Here is another simple approach.  This uses an extension I wrote, [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform), to do a find and replace in the current document and do the necessary math.

Try this keybinding:

```json
{
  "key": "alt+c",               // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "description": "convert px to rem",
    "find": "(\\d+)prem",
    "isRegex": true,

    "replace": [
      "$${",
        "const ratio = 16;",                      // your base conversion ratio
        "let result = Number($1/ratio).toFixed(1);",
        "result = result.replace('.0', '');",    // if ends with .0, remove it
        "return result + 'rem';",
      "}$$",
    ],

    // omit 'restrictFind' to replace all in whole document
    // "restrictFind": "line",  // to do for line at cursor
  }
}
```

Use `"restrictFind": "line",` to make the change on every line with a cursor.  Omit the `"restrictFind"` to replace for entire document.

---

You don't really need to use the `prem` syntax.  You could just change tie `find` regex to `(\\d+)px` to convert those values (and replace them line by line, or all of them, or the next one, etc.).